# How position divs horizontally inside another div

Tags: css

I have a php script that is generating an unspecified number of divs inside another but by default the divs are being vertically aligned as in one of top of the other though their widths can allow for them to be horizontally aligned. How can i go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
div > div{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Good answer but... If you need to support older browsers. For cross browser compatibility, be careful of the ">" selector (no IE6 support) http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html. Also be careful of "inline-block": IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural display: inline (div's natural display is block) http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html.

Comment: @Alex: Good points, however there are workarounds for IE (typical...). For inline block stuff, give this a go: `display: inline-block; zoom: 1; *display: inline`.

Comment: @JamWaffles very true, there are workarounds - good point I should of added that to my comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex: No problem. Do note that the above code won't validate (I think). IE is a wonderfully depressing piece of "software".

Answer (score 2):

float them to left

```
float:left;
```

or give them inline display mode.

```
display:inline;
```

Comment: the float:left option failed to work in my case but display:inline-block worked...

Comment: Bakuradze, I'm not certain (I haven't tried it), but I think floated items also need a width.